# How to profile application running in Tomcat 6 on Solaris 10 Sparc Server?

Tags: flex3, jakarta-ee, solaris, tomcat6

My J2EE based application running in Tomcat 6 on Solaris 10 sparc server is very very slow.
It works fine on Linux servers. I am using flex as web front end to my application.

I need to know how can I configure and run it using any java profiler on Sun Solaris server.

Comment: I will try out jprofiler 6 next week for my tomcat app. 
Will keep this posted updated for results achieved and are those satisfactory.

http://www.ej-technologies.com/download/jprofiler/files.html

Comment: It ended up Solaris install issue. I updated to Solaris 10 update 5 and server seems to work fine. Will keep updated if I find again it is slow.

Comment: Consider using VisualVM for quick initial investigation -- https://visualvm.dev.java.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

visualvm doesn't work remotely.

I used [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/download/jprofiler/files.html). Not completely solved this problem using it (As mentioned in my comments , there seemed to be more of an Solaris installation ), But it was helpful.